# How can I show plot data in a popup box when I move the mouse to the marker in the plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have following lines of code to generate a plot as shown below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpldatacursor import datacursor
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import datetime

date = [datetime.date(2015, 7, 1), datetime.date(2015, 8, 1), datetime.date(2015, 9, 1), datetime.date(2015, 10, 1), datetime.date(2015, 11, 1), datetime.date(2015, 12, 1), datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), datetime.date(2016, 2, 1)]
people = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 38]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
lns1 = ax1.plot(date, people, 'ro')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

datacursor(ax1, hover=True, formatter='customer: {y:0.0f}'.format)
plt.show()
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

What I am trying to do is, to show popup box when I hover on to the marker. But with my code I get pop up appear wherever I move the cursor.

Also is it possible to display date in that popup?

Comment: What is `datacursor`? Where does it come from? If you wrote that function yourself, you need to make the code available, if it's a third party function, link to it and show how you import it.

Comment: It is a built in function. I came to know about this from https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor

Comment: How do you import it then? Please [edit] your question to incorporate this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've attached your `datacursor` to the `axes` object rather than the plot itself so it will be triggered whenver you move the mouse anywhere within the axes. If you instead attach it to the plot, it will only trigger when you're over a data point.

```
datacursor(lns1, hover=True, formatter='customer: {y:0.0f}'.format)
```

If you want to show the date in the cursor, you can get the major tick formatter from the xaxis and use that as your formatter for your data cursor

```
# Get the formatter that's being used on the axes
xformatter = plt.gca().xaxis.get_major_formatter()

# Apply it to your data cursor
datacursor(lns1, hover=True, formatter= lambda **kwargs: xformatter(kwargs.get('x')))
```

If you want to specify a *different* format than that used on the x axis, you can use a [`DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) object with a custom format string.

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

fmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
datacursor(lns1, hover=True, formatter= lambda **kwargs: fmt(kwargs.get('x')))
```

**Update**

If you want the customer label and the date you can do

```
fmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
datacursor(lns1, hover=True, formatter= lambda **kwargs: 'customer: {y:.0f}'.format(**kwargs) + 'date: ' + fmt(kwargs.get('x')))
```

As a side-note, `datacursor` is not built-in like you mentioned. It's part of [`mpldatacursor`](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor).

Comment: yes i got it. I already fixed it :) I am looking for showing date in popup

Comment: @nas Updated with some details on how to do that

Comment: how can I put label in that pop up. E.g. (customer: 40 , date: 2017-2-3). I tried but I get syntax error everytime. Thank you for your help

Comment: @nas Updated with an example